# Prolog , return permutations with a max value

Tags: prolog, return, max, permutation

i have made predicate schedule(A,B,C) that returns possible permutations at lists A,B,C with backtracking

```
| ?- schedule(A,B,C).

A = [im204,im212,im217]
B = [im209,im214,im218]
C = [im210,im216] ? ;

A = [im204,im212,im218]
B = [im209,im214,im217]
C = [im210,im216] ? ;

A = [im204,im212,im216]
B = [im209,im214,im218]
C = [im210,im217] ?
```

I also have the predicate schedule_score(A,B,C,S) which returns score(dont mind what the score means) from lists A,B,C to S.

```
| ?-  score_schedule([im204,im209,im212],[im210,im214,im216],[im217,im218],S).

S = 578
```

In my new predicate

```
all_schedule_scores(A,B,C,S):-
   schedule(A,B,C),
   score_schedule(A,B,C,S).
```

it returns possible permutations along with the score

```
| ?- all_schedule_scores(A,B,C,S).

A = [im204,im212,im217]
B = [im209,im214,im218]
C = [im210,im216]
S = 342 ? ;

A = [im204,im212,im218]
B = [im209,im214,im217]
C = [im210,im216]
S = 371 ? ;

A = [im204,im212,im216]
B = [im209,im214,im218]
C = [im210,im217]
S = 294 ?
```

I was wondering if there was a way i can return only the permutations with the max score(or not return any permutations whose score isnt max).

Comment: This is a little unclear. Do you want to succeed only on the schedule that has the greatest score of all of them? Or are you wanting to provide a max score and only succeed on those schedules that have a score greater than or equal to what you provide?

Comment: only on the schedule with max score. For instance if max score is 620 then it will return that one. If there are more with 620 it will return with backtrack

Comment: Did you try querying, `all_schedule_scores(A,B,C,620).`?

Comment: `all_schedule_scores(A,B,C,620)` should give you all `A, B, C` values that correspond to a score of 620. If you want "greater than or equal to 620" then you'll need to include a new constraint in your predicate clause.

Comment: 620 was an example, i am trying to find a way so it returns the max score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what Prolog implementation you're using. Here's a solution that uses `setof/3` (which orders its results low to high):

```
max_scored(MaxA, MaxB, MaxC, MaxS) :-
    setof((S,A,B,C), all_scheduled_scores(A,B,C,S), AllScoresLowToHigh), 
    reverse(AllScoresLowToHigh, [(MaxS,MaxA,MaxB,MaxC)|_]).
```

Sorting uses a natural ordering, so `(S1,A1,B1,C1)` is considered greater than `(S2,A2,B2,C2)` if `S1` is greater than `S2`.

This solution just finds a single maximum result. If you have multiple that are at the same maximum, I'll leave that as an exercise for you. You would just need to choose the first elements of the 2nd argument to `reverse/2` that have the same score.

Comment: First of all let me thank you because your solution works. Could you elaborate though what you mean when you say "You would just need to choose the first elements of the 2nd argument to reverse/2 that have the same score."?

Comment: @Gluxable what I meant by that comment is that you're starting with a list that has elements ordered from highest to lowest score. If more than one element has the same highest score, you'd need to create a predicate that looks at a list, and succeeds for each element that has the same score as the first element. Specifically, your "second argument to reverse" looks like `[(MaxS, MaxA, MaxB, MaxC)|_]`. The "first elements" are the `MaxS` values. If my answer is acceptable, consider accepting it by clicking the check mark. :)

Answer (score 0):

If your Prolog supports it, you could use library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)):

```
max_scored_schedule(ScA,ScB,ScC,Score) :-
    aggregate(max(S,[A,B,C]), (schedule(A,B,C),score_schedule(A,B,C,S)), max(Score,[ScA,ScB,ScC])).
```

Tested with hardcoded data you provided:

```
?- max_scored_schedule(A,B,C,S).
A = [im204, im209, im212],
B = [im210, im214, im216],
C = [im217, im218],
S = 578.
```

As you can see, it's just a matter to properly order arguments...

*Edit*:

library([solutionsequences](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=solutionsequences)) allows for a SQL like query, that should solve your problem

```
?- order_by([desc(S)], group_by(S, (A,B,C), (schedule(A,B,C),score_schedule(A,B,C,S)), G)).
```

but the straightforward answer by @lurker is neat (+1), and doesn't require you to port another library to your Prolog

Comment: It looks like the aggregate library is not built in my Prolog. Is there a way to add it manually?

Comment: library(aggregate) it's fairly sophisticated, porting to another Prolog (btw, which one are you using ?) it's not a task for beginners... but if your Prolog has support for nb_setarg/3, see [my snippet here](https://github.com/CapelliC/prolog-snippets/blob/master/lag.pl) for inspiration :)

Comment: I managed to use aggregate by downling SWI prolog and getting the library aggregate.pl and use it in GNU prolog. However aggregate only returns one solution while i need all solutions with max score

Comment: Good job! Didn't know porting to GProlog was easy. Could you share your experience ?